# Keycloak themes: How to use redirectUri?

Tags: keycloak

In my login theme I want to render a link back to the 'original' app. '/register' should become '#ORIGIN#/register'.

I tried:

```
<a href="<#if pageRedirectUri??>${pageRedirectUri}/register<#else>/register</#if>">Register</a>
```

Without success. `${pageRedirectUri}` is never set.

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, you want to use your own register mechanism instead of Keycloak's?

Comment: Correct. We already built a register mechanism and now want to introduce Keycloak. We want to use Keycloak for user management but don't want to spend time on modelling the UI in Keycloak and instead use our existing UI. The register endpoint will then use the Keycloak API to create the user via backend.

Comment: Doing the login page was easy and the most basic feature we require from Keycloak.